# Compile issue with tuples and variadic templates

Tags: c++, tuples, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, decltype

I'm having an issue with a seemingly complicated problem.

I'm trying to make an iterator class for a zip function (trying to mimic python's generator zip function).

I have the entire class at http://ideone.com/c7rm40

```
  template<size_t I = 0, typename... Tp>
  inline typename std::enable_if<(I == sizeof...(Tp)), typename std::tuple<decltype(*Tp)...>>::type
  constructImpl(std::tuple<Tp...> const& its) {

core/StarAlgorithm.hpp|550 col 3| error: expected ‘(’ before ‘constructImpl’
core/StarAlgorithm.hpp|550 col 3| error: expected ‘>’ before ‘constructImpl’
core/StarAlgorithm.hpp|550 col 45| error: template argument 2 is invalid
core/StarAlgorithm.hpp|550 col 47| error: expected ‘::’ before ‘{’ token
core/StarAlgorithm.hpp|550 col 47| error: expected identifier before ‘{’ token
core/StarAlgorithm.hpp|550 col 47| error: expected unqualified-id before ‘{’ token
```

My question is, is this approach even valid?  I can't figure out why it's necessarily wrong, or what the compiler wants from me.

But beyond that, if there is a simpler approach I am missing, I would be overjoyed to hear it.

Comment: `typename std::tuple<decltype(*Tp)...>` should not have `typename`. Not sure if this is the problem though.

Comment: Why is there `*` in `decltype(*Tp)`? And why are you using `decltype` to begin with? `Tp` *is* a type itself.

Comment: I added it in as something to try, I've been halfway hacking on this for a while just to rule out things.  It doesn't work with `typename` removed either.

Comment: @Nawaz, Because this function takes a tuple of iterators of various types, dereferences them, and returns a tuple of the dereferenced types.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity: `decltype` doesn't apply on *type*. and `*Tp` doesn't even make sense! `Tp` is not a pointer value, it is a type!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the problem is that `*Tp` is not a valid expression for `decltype`.

Maybe try `declval`?

```
std::tuple<decltype(*std::declval<Tp>())...>
```

Or iterator traits:

```
 std::tuple<typename std::iterator_traits<Tp>::value_type...>
```

Comment: declval doesn't work, but iterator_traits works wonderfully.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
typename std::tuple<decltype(*Tp)...>>::type
```

This doesn't make sense at all, because:

- `Tp` is a type argument, so `*Tp` doesn't make any sense.
- `std::tuple` doesn't have any nested `::type`. So `std::tuple<whatever>::type` doesn't make sense.

Based on your comments, I *guess* you need [`std::iterator_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits) as:

```
std::tuple<typename std::iterator_traits<Tp>::value_type...>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: The problem with remove pointer is that AFAIK it only works on pointers, not iterators in general.

Comment: @Pubby: Alright. In that case, `std::iterator_traits` would work!